# Background location iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I need to capture device location independently if app was killed, I have enable background modes location updates and background fetch also I have on app delegate the locationManager with startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges. Currently I print each location update received.It works perfectly with app on foreground and when app is minimized, but when app is closed (double click Home button and remove) I dont receive updates. According to some forums and sites app should be called on background with each new location update but it dont works.

[image: Background modes enabled]
[image: LocationManager]
[image: Logs on foreground and minimized app]
[image: killing app]
[image: No receive any location update]

Comment: What are you hoping to do with the location changes? I'm pretty sure the app can't log like that after it's in the background like that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Can I Continue updating my location even when app is killed or removed from background in ios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39343033/how-can-i-continue-updating-my-location-even-when-app-is-killed-or-removed-from)

Answer (score 0):

If the app is closed, it can't report location. The only thing that apps can do while closed is show notifications.

Answer (score 0):

If the app is force closed by the user it will not be able to continue to update the users location in the background, there is nothing that works around this.

from the app life cycle documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW6

> In addition to the system terminating your app, the user can
>   terminate your app explicitly using the multitasking UI.
>   User-initiated termination has the same effect as terminating a
>   suspended app. The app’s process is killed and no notification is sent
>   to the app.